# how to detect drag begins in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I know from this question how to handle a drag&Drop

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872857/982161

but I can not detect when the Drag event begins so I can prepare some resources...

if I print those events the Drop is coming first and after that the Drag..

how can this be cleanly handled

My Code is pretty simple

```
    private void Label_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var lbl = (Label)sender;
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Content, DragDropEffects.Move);
        Console.WriteLine("Drag...");
    }

    private void Label_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drop...");
    }

    private void Label_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Label_DragEnter...");
    }

    private void Label_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Label_DragLeave...");
    }
```

Comment: [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.110).aspx) seems pretty *talkative* about it.

Comment: yap, but nothing related to Drag begins....

Comment: Drag begins when you call `DragDrop.DoDragDrop()` and it's typically a `MouseMove` event (where you simple check if left mouse button is pressed to start it). Maybe this is your problem: trying to start it in `MouseDown`?

Comment: DragDrop.DoDragDrop() is what am doing in the MouseDown, doing it in the MouseMove will trigger the event several times

Comment: You need to check for the mouse left button pressed - MouseMove events stop once the left button is clicked. See example here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

Long story short: If you want to prepare resources before you drop the label, write that code before calling the `DragDrop` method or in the `OnPreviewMouseDown` event.

---

Long Story:

Using [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) I was able to look into the events that are triggering when dragging the label.

It appears that the only events triggering are the `PreviewMouseDown` and `MouseDown`.

[image]

So we should only implement those events.

```
private void Lbl_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var lbl = (Label)sender;
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Content, DragDropEffects.Move);
    Console.WriteLine("Drag...");
}

private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Label_PreviewMouseDown...");
}
```

This will result in first printing "Label_PreviewMouseDown..." when starting to drag the label and "Drag..." when the label is done being dragged.

[image]

However, this isn't the complete truth.

Let's modify our code a little. Let's add `DateTime.Now.Second` to test when the messages are actually triggering. I will then drag the label for a few seconds, then drop it to see the order of printing to console.

```
private void Lbl_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var lbl = (Label)sender;

    Console.WriteLine("Label_OnMouseDown_BeforeDragging..." + DateTime.Now.Second);

    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Content, DragDropEffects.Move);

    Console.WriteLine("Label_OnMouseDown_AfterDragging..." + DateTime.Now.Second);
}

private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Label_PreviewMouseDown..." + DateTime.Now.Second);
}
```

Now let's try dragging again.

[image]

Turns out that `OnMouseDown` happens before you are done dragging. The `DoDragDrop` method pauses the code there until you drop the label, then you are able to continue and print to the console.

So therefore: If you want to prepare resources before you drop the label, write that code before calling the `DragDrop` method or in the `OnPreviewMouseDown` event.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a drag event that is not provided by the control then you may consider adding one to your own code. For example

```
// Event fired immediately before DragDrop
public DragEventHandler DragBegin { get; set; }

private void Label_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var lbl = (Label)sender;

    // Create args object and fire event if not null
    var args = new DragEventArgs(new DataObject(lbl.Content), DragDropKeyStates.None, DragDropEffects.None, lbl, e.GetPoint(lbl));
    DragBegin?.Invoke(sender, args);

    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Content, DragDropEffects.Move);
    Console.WriteLine("Drag...");
}
```

You could then bind to that event from anywhere you have a reference to that code behind, such as

```
MyUserControl.DragBegin += (sender, args) => /* some behavior */;
```